# Typescript Generic type 'Omit' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, generics, visual-studio-code

Taking the below example directly from typescript official website; it works in the code playground [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5gNyHKYQ0IMAOJ6IanQYgWbBOgC2PCpEzUARunQU4IVgF98%20MAE8eKDNgAKUCADdgEAO7IAvMgDyk0gB4j6ADTIARBy68-CA%20AHys%20BIgdMRY6NQephZWtg4ERCTkVL4AwqogyFDKkj6e4lIyEHLU8GQ0EKUa4UA)
however in vscode with typescript 4.0 installed, the

> Omit<Todo, `description`>

is giving me a Generic type 'Omit' requires 2 type argument(s) error

```
interface Todo {
    title: string
    description: string
    completed: boolean
}

type TodoPreview = Omit<Todo, `description`>

const todo: TodoPreview = {
    title: 'Clean room',
    completed: false
}
```

Comment: `\`description\`` -> `'description'`

Comment: Yes that was it! so typescript does not allow backticks, cue lint config issues :/
P.S Can't mark as answer as your reply is a comment